# Column Validation check passes on Create but fails on Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-validation, validation-error

I'm trying to validate that a month column is within 30 days of the create date in SharePoint online using the validation below:

```
=AND([Start Month]<(Created+30),[Start Month]>(Created-30))
```

This works as expected when creating a list item, failing when the date is outside of the range, but when editing rows it always gives me an error even if I haven't changed the Start Month column.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Validation settings]

[image: Error on Edit only]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue in my environment.

You could try this workaround:

```
1.Create a calculated column, and use this formula : =[Start Month]-[Created]

2.Change the list validation to this: =AND([calculated]<30,[calculated]>-30)
```

Comment: Kind of an ugly work around but it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your use case and ran into the same issue. However, I looked at the default settings for the 'Created' column, I realized that it defaults to the 'Friendly' setting (meaning it spells out the date in words as opposed to using a number format, i.e. 3/21/2019). Once I switched it to 'Standard', your formula worked as expected.

[image]

Comment: Still isn't working for me. I tried creating an entire new list as well and setting Created to Standard from the beginning without success.